# Drupal 7 Improved Multiselect and Ajax

Tags: ajax

I am developing an events module for an Alumni Website.

In there, have 2 selects -

**Select 1** - is to select a batch (that is year of passing ex. 1994, 1995, 1996 etc)

**Select 2** - Is the Improved Multiselect using the Module - https://www.drupal.org/project/improved_multi_select

OnChange of Select 1, Select 2 is populated with all the users of that batch. This logic is working good.

But, when I change the batch the selected users are not saved.

Say suppose, I select 1994 batch, Out of the 100 Ex-Students I have selected 2, now I need 1 ex-student from 2000 batch, so I change the batch but the 2 selected students are not saved.

My Current Code is -

```
   function alumni_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
       global $user;     

    switch ($form_id){
        case 'event_node_form':
            $main_organizing_members_options = array();
            $batch = 0;


            if(isset($form_state['values'])) { // Get values only after form submit
                $batch = $form_state['values']['field_year_of_passing_x']['und'][0]['value'];

            }

        $form['field_year_of_passing_x']['und']['#ajax'] = array(
            'event' => 'change',
            'wrapper' => drupal_html_id('organizing-mem-wrapper'),
            'callback' => 'organizing_members_ajax_callback',
            'method' => 'replace',
            'limit_validation_errors'=>array()
        );                      

        $main_organizing_members_options = alumni_organising_members($batch);

        $selected = isset($form_state['values']['field_main_organizing_members']['und']) ? $form_state['values']['field_main_organizing_members']['und'] : '0' ;
        $form['field_main_organizing_members']['und'] =array(
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#multiple' => TRUE,
            '#prefix' => '<div id="organizing-mem-wrapper">',
            '#suffix' => '</div>',
            '#options' => $main_organizing_members_options,
            '#default_value' =>  $selected
            );

        break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return $form;


}


function organizing_members_ajax_callback($form, $form_state) {   
    $batch = $form['field_year_of_passing_x']['und']['#value'];

    $form['field_main_organizing_members']['und']['#options'] = alumni_organising_members($batch);

    return $form['field_main_organizing_members'];
}


function alumni_organising_members($batch) {
     $organizing_members = array();

    $SQL = "SQL query to fetch all the Ex-Students if batch is not select ";
    if($batch > 0)
        $SQL .= "WHERE BATCH =".$batch; 

    $organizing_members = db_query($SQL)->fetchAllKeyed();
    return $organizing_members;
}
?>
```

All the help is appreciated. Am stuck with this for quite sometime now. Thanks.